# Python - Tkinter: Window class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

How can you create a window in tkinter with a class?

i know `root = Tk()` is the standard way to do it, but if i want to make a class that create a "window" in python that i can add buttons to later on who is that done?

I get this error from the code down below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/euc/PycharmProjects/Skole/Shortcut/Gui2.py", line 26, in <module>
    b = Create_button(a)
  File "C:/Users/euc/PycharmProjects/Skole/Shortcut/Gui2.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.button = Button(window, text=text)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2161, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2084, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2062, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'Create_window' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Create_window(): #Create a window
    win = Tk()
    def __init__(self):
        self = Tk()
        self.title("This is title Name")

class Create_button: # Create a button within the window
    text = "None"
    button_width = 15
    button_height = 10

    def __init__(self, window, text="null"):
        if text == "null": #Set text to none if none parameter is passed
            text = self.text

        self.button = Button(window, text=text)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)



a = Create_window()  # Create window
b = Create_button(a) # Create button within Window

a.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just a quick note, you declare to 2 different Tk() in your code. Win = Tk() and self = Tk(). I hear that leads to many problems.

Comment: Yes. Not advisable. That's why I have removed the unnecessary ones and modified the OP's code in my answer.

Comment: I did that, in hope it would work if i did a.win, didnt work etiher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass `Toplevel` to do this. Check [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) out for more on `Toplevel`.

Also I have cleaned up and restructured your code a little. Compare your code and this and note the differences and changes made for some better practices.

Pay attention to class name conventions as opposed to method name conventions. Class names usually don't start with a verb or action word, because essentially classes are objects or nouns. Functions and methods on the other hand must start with a verb or action word.

You don't need to use a class to create a button for what looks like something that can be put in a single function.

Here's the modified snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyWindow(Toplevel): #Create a window
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.title("This is title Name")


def create_button(frame, text="None"): # Create a button within the frame given
    button_width = 15
    button_height = 10

    frame.button = Button(frame, text=text)
    frame.button. configure(height=button_height, width=button_width)
    frame.button.grid(row=0, column=0)


app = Tk()
a = MyWindow(master=app)  # Create window
create_button(a) # Create button within Window

app.mainloop()
```

Also make sure to check this out for a [great tutorial](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) on using and subclassing Toplevel to create dialogs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is was a huge help! as good as it can get ;) Thanks a lot @kartikg3 Highly appreciated :)